# div jumps down occasionally in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

I just encountered a very strange error using Chrome. Everything worked fine until recently.
The divs are jumping down occasionally, almost like a clear was applied to them.

I made a test page to show you guys, you have to reload sometimes in order to see it. The "Float-left" and "Float-right" is only side by side occasionally.

[Visit the test page](http://www.playsharp.se/user-test.php)

I tried several diffrent computers and browsers, it only happens in Chrome and on this computer. I did not change any code, it just started acting like this today.

I really want to solve this problem as fast as i can, as it happens almost every page-load on [the main site](http://www.playsharp.se).

I found several matching threads here at Stack, i created the test page with the answers in mind, but the problem still occurs.

Thanks in advance /Jimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean why is the `<input class="user-content-right-test">` sometimes going down, it's because you have in `<div id="user-content">` **clear:both;**. Remove the **clear** and it won't go down.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer Vucko, i shall try this as soon as i get home. I have a question tough, how can the elements inside user-content not be floated side by side because it has clear:both? Chrome bug?

Comment: @JimmyBergstedt the elements inside are floated, you can see that when you inspect the element. If you want to **clear** after the float, you must put `<div style="clear:both>` after the `<div id="user-content">`.

Comment: I have managed to get it right with this information, thanks alot Vucko !